# signin google-services.json android

Tags: android, android-activity

I created and download a google-services.json file to integrate push notifications in my app.
Now I want to integrate google login in my app, it asks again to download a google-services.json. 
If I download this, the old one will be replaced.
Is there anyway I can configure google sign in through this google-services.json only?

Comment: the new file will have all the services(api) included only so you dont need to worry about the old json

Comment: Maybe [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597953/what-does-google-services-json-really-do/33083898#33083898) helps you.

Comment: but i am getting handleSignInResult:false everytime I am trying to login