# GCM - do i need to save one "google-services"(json file) on two diffrent projects?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i have two projects in android studio. the first one is called "test1" and the second is "test2". i want to use google cloud messaging to communicate with each other. my question is, do i need to use the same "google-services json file (downloaded from google website) on both projects, and also the same project id?
or use diffrent google-services files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand the *communication* word between two different projects. (You mean example to say Facebook send push notifications to Twitter ? )

If you have two different Projects, **Yes** you need two `google-services.json` files because both projects have different *package names* and *Sender-ID*(i.e Project ID in google console )

If you want communication between two application's (not two different projects), then you can simply use **ONE** `google-services.json` file

Note: With out `google-services.json` file also Servies works well in production but not after releasing your app in public.

Also read [What is google-services.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31598587/5955593) to get clear idea of it.

Comment: alright thanks! you answered my question. just another question,i can send notification from "test1" to "test2" with sender id?

Comment: but if they are projects?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use two different json files, because first project package name and second project package name are different. Google will generate server key depends on package name.