# GCM Google-services.json storing api key

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am implementing GCM with android client and according to the google documentation I need to download the google-services.json and add it to the module. I notice that the google-services.json contains the api key for the project. Is it wise to include the api key in the project?

In my scenario I have to use GCM with android using AWS, in the aws documentation they are simply adding the project number for registration

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html

But in android studio when I add dependency in the build.gradle I am getting compilation error for missing google-services.json.

com.google.gms:google-services:

so my question is there a way I can skip the google-services.json in the android studio project? and if not then is it wise to include the api key in that file?

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0):

As have been discussed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597953/what-does-google-services-json-really-do), "google-services.json contains developer credentials and configuration settings, which is needed to verify while connecting with GoogleApiClient". However, it was also mentioned that GCM has been used before without google-services.json .