# FirebaseRemoteConfig: Fetch failed! Server responded with an error. 400

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879661/no-google-services-json-but-still-fetching-the-remote-config-from-my-firebase-pr) was my previous question.

Now, I deleted Firebase Project for test. And trying to connect it to the real Firebase Project.

I added `google-services.json` of the real one in my project and I get this error. ( already tried in `/app/` and `/app/src/`

```
E/FirebaseRemoteConfig: Fetch failed! Server responded with an error.
    com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zze: 400 Bad Request
    {
      "code": 400,
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "global",
          "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
          "reason": "badRequest"
        }
      ],
      "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzn.zza(Unknown Source:14)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzh.zzb(Unknown Source:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzab.zzac(Unknown Source:184)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzf.zzi(Unknown Source:51)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzes.zzc(Unknown Source:49)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzes.zzb(Unknown Source:23)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzes.zza(Unknown Source:168)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.then(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I added `SHA-1` from `signingReport(debug)`. However, still doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not pretty sure but I think it was because at least one of the reasons.

1. Cache problem.
2. Delay problem.

I tried invalidate&restart&clean build&delete abb. However, It didn't work. But later on, It works. I don't know why.

If you have a problem with it for a long time, then go to ask Firebase customer centre.